# You're given a list of $n$ days. How many ways can you pick a pair of days such that the first comes before the second?

Tags: probability, algorithms

This is a problem that's introduced in *Introduction to Algorithms* on the maximum subarray problem.

Very briefly, the main problem is something like this: You're given data on the price of a stock over $n$ days, and you'd like to find a pair of days that would maximize your profit (one day = buy, the other = sell).

The book begins by considering the brute-force approach, which is to consider all possible $(buy, sell)$ day combinations. The book claims that for $n$ days, there are ${n \choose 2}$ ways to pick such days.

This doesn't seem right to me, and I'd like to get some clarification. Here is how I've worked out the computations so far:

---

Consider the array $[day1, day2, day3, ..., dayn]$. Obviously, we can't ever buy the stock on $dayn$ because then we can't sell it. So I believe there are only $n-1$ options for the purchase day.

As for the second day (sell), let's consider this. You could pick the following for the purchase date and have the corresponding number of sell options:

- $day1$: $n-1$ options (all days except $day1$ itself)

OR

- $day2$: $n-2$ options (all days except $day1$ and $day2$

OR

- $day3$: $n-3$ options (all days except $day1$, $day2$, and $day3$)

OR

...

OR

- $day(n-1)$: $1$ option (namely, the $n$th day)

So this is a summation:

$1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (n-1)$

And that's $\frac{(n-1)(n)}{2}$.

So that's how many options we have for the $sell$ day. Giving us a total asymptotic complexity for the number of choices of:

$(n-1) \times \frac{(n-1)(n)}{2} = O(n^3) $ in Big-O notation

---

Again, the book claims it's ${n \choose 2}$ and that this is really $O(n^2)$. Where am I going wrong in my understanding?

Comment: I think I found my mistake. It's not $(n-1) \times \frac{(n-1)(n)}{2}$. It's just $\times \frac{(n-1)(n)}{2}$... I think.

Comment: Just choose different days.  You must have bought it before you sold it.  (Assuming no short sales.)  There are ${n\choose2}$ choices.

Comment: Is my (corrected) math at least valid reasoning? The bullets + my comment here?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: If you're listing the number of possible sale days for each purchase day and then adding, then you *already* have a complete list of (purchase, sale) pairs. There's no need to multiply again by the number of purchase days.

Comment: @ConnorHarris Right, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: I think I also now understand why it's ${n \choose 2}$—because it doesn't matter what order the days are in. We just need two days on hand, and then we can obviously designate the smaller one to be the purchase date. So it's a combination problem.